# How to fix mat-autocomplete while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, material-ui

After opening mat-autocomplete, when I scroll my page then I want mat-autocomplete to be sticky.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
@ViewChild('alertInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger })
  autoComplete: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

Step 2: Write this line on ngOnInit()

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
```

Step 3: Define this function

```
scrollEvent = (event: any): void => {
    if (this.autoComplete.panelOpen) this.autoComplete.updatePosition();
  }
```